# problem when css/bootstrap/js to my twig template

Tags: css, symfony, authentication, twig

the login works perfectly fine with the simple form

but when I try to add bootstrap/css/js to it , its doesn't work anymore  the

`{% if error %}
 <span class="error">{{ error.messageKey }} </span>
{% endif %}`
 
shows ( Invalid credentials. ) error!

I just cant find where is the error

Here is the code of the simple form :

```
        <form action=" {{ path ('login') }} " method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="_username" value"{{ last_username }}" placeholder="username here.">
        <input type="password" name="_password" >
        <button type="submit"> login </button>
        </form>
```

here is the code of the form (with css/bootstrap/js)

```
<form  action=" {{ path ('login') }} " method="POST"  class="login100-form validate-form">
                    <div class="login100-form-avatar">
                        <img src="{{ asset('/logo.jpg') }}" alt="AVATAR">
                    </div>

                    <span class="login100-form-title p-t-20 p-b-45">
                        Bazar-Chic Login page
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-10" data-validate = "Username is required">
                        <input class="input100" value="{{ last_username }}"  type="text" name="_username" placeholder="Username">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-10" data-validate = "Password is required">
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn p-t-10">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn">
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center w-full p-t-25 p-b-230">
                        <a href="#" class="txt1">
                            Forgot Username / Password?
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center w-full">
                        <a class="txt1" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/register">
                            Create an account
                            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>                      
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Are you sure your form gets posted to the controller and it's not a javascript validation you are encountering after adding bootstrap's JS?

Comment: Does the behavior change if you use: `<span class="error">{{ error }} </span>`  I just removed the _.messageKey._

Comment: If the error is "Invalid credentials..." the problem probably lies within your bootstrap.ini.

Comment: no no , i edited my code , the problem is on the form (check my code again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Barbie said the problem was with the name of the input.

(`name="pass" => name="_password"`)

The problem is solved and the topic can be locked!
Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change:

`name="pass"` to `name="_password"`

Comment: The reason I downvoted is because this answer looks more like a comment. Answers should not start with "Maybe"

Comment: I said "Maybe" because he only post the front.